# Python relative import to invoke script from random directory

Tags: python, import, pythonpath, relative-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
test1/
test1/a.py
test1/test2/b.py
```

b.py needs to import a class in a.py. So I can add the following line to b.py before importing a.

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + "/..")

This works and I can invoke b.py from any directory and it is able to import a.
But this fails when I write a script in another directory to invoke this file using execfile().

I tried relative imports but I get a "Attempted Relative Import in Non-Package error"

```
from ..a import someclass as cls
```

I have `__init__.py` in both test1, test2

Does someone have an idea how to make it work?
Is `PYTHONPATH` the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `execfile` will evaluate the file you are calling as pure python code. Every relative import statement inside of `b.py` (and any package module imported by it)  will have to remain true to your calling script.

One solution is to not use any relative import paths within the package. Make sure `test1` package is on your PYTHONPATH as well.

**b.py**

```
from test1 import a
```

With `test1` in your PYTHONPATH, the import of `a` should success in your `execfile`

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/path/to/parent/of_test1')
>>> execfile('/path/to/parent/of_test1/test1/test2/b.py')
```

Comment: I do have `__init__.py`. Still it does not work.
`__file__` is no good when I a third script invokes b.py using execfile. print `__file__` prints name of other file.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: I think you are going to face problems no matter what if you are trying to allow a script to `execfile` a module in a package that is dependent on other modules. `execfile` evaluates the pure code of the module, so everything that was relative in the module must also be relative similarly in the exec'ing script

Comment: I guess you are right. I guess I need to play around to find a more convenient build environment solution.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: I just rewrote my answer